# jQuery repeatable functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery and am trying to figure out how to repeat functions. As you can see from the code below when clicked on the button it will turn to 'I was clicked' in an h1 and then when clicked again it will go back to 'Click Me' however of course it stops after that. Without having to continuously write those lines over and over again, what is the easiest way to have it repeat so anytime I click on it it changes?

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $(this).html("<h1>I was clicked</h1>");
  $(this).click(function() {
    $(this).html("Click Me")
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<button>Click Me</button>
<button>Click Me</button>
<button>Click Me</button>
<button>Click Me</button>
<button>Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a couple of functions to use as event handlers, and assign the other function as the event handler when one gets called:

```js
function clickme() {
  $(this).html("Click Me");
  $(this).off('click').click(clicked);
}

function clicked() {
  $(this).html("<h1>I was clicked</h1>");
  $(this).off('click').click(clickme);
}

$("button").click(clicked);
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <button>Click Me</button>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Using this method, I recommend pruning old event handlers so they don't [accumulate](https://jsfiddle.net/hpa4nx3j/), something like `$(this).off('click').click(...)`. See [`off()`](https://api.jquery.com/off/).

Comment: @showdev good point; I've edited to do that.

Comment: @mikeymike Please see my edit, it prevents the buttons getting multiple event handlers (which eventually could cause memory/speed issues)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$("button").click(function() {

  if ($(this).html().indexOf("I was clicked") == -1)
    $(this).html("<h1>I was clicked</h1>");
  else
    $(this).html("Click Me")

});
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <button>Click Me</button>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```